Set self-view location in Webex Web
I am using Webex Web for my profession in a private firefox session without any plugins. It seems somewhen I changed the location of my self-view to a floating window. Now, I would like to change it back to be displayed with all others again.
I web-searched where to set the preferences and found The WebEx help center. But this does not help.
The floating window does not feature the (…) button on the upper right. The video preferences on the bottom of the page (near the mute button) only features camera selection, virtual background and camera resolution. The regular settings button in the main window of the meeting does not feature any camera settings.
Can anyone help me change the self-view settings back to default?
